# PowerQuery - running difference columns - a bit like running totals

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I'm having a articular problem which I'm not sure of the best way to describe.

I am trying to generate a running total and a running difference column in PowerQuery /  (the transform part of PowerBI ).

I am looking at population data for 4 different locations in an area by gender.
So there is a gender population and a total population for a location. And by extension there is an area gender and area total population.

For example

[image]

On a certain date I'm counting the number of people who eat a hamburger.
(I'm not, but I'm trying to keep it generic).

On this day there will be a total population for a location.

For example

[image]

I want to generate columns for

a running total of :
people who have eaten a hamburger at that location (so today's value (tv) added to yesterday's value (yv) )
male who have eaten a hamburger at that location
female who have eaten a hamburger at that location

A running difference of:
people who have yet to eat a hamburger at that location (so location population yesterday (lpy) - tv)
males who have yet to eat a hamburger at that location
females who have yet to eat a hamburger at that location

With that defined, it should become easier to build the powerquery up so it's possible to calculate:

the total number of men in a location who have/not eaten a hamburger on a certain date
the population of men in that location who have/not eaten a hamburger on a certain date

And so on so that you can calculate how many men in an location have/have not eaten hamburger and how this contributes to the total location proportion and the area proportions of hamburger consumption.

I can quickly generate a quick measure in BI to perform a running total. But the problem I'm having is creating a more complicated running total. And indeed if I'm running this the right way?

I have a table of aggregated data with the population denominator for an area. I want to on a line by line basis in a processed table the remaining population, so that I can say "x % of men, y % of women, xy% of people in location 1 have/have not eaten hamburgers".

I'm not even sure if splitting the table to locations would be right.

Summary: I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: A frequently used method to refer to a previous row in PQ is with an `Index` column. However, that can be slow with large data. A faster method would be to create a new column that is ***one-off*** the current column by inserting a null at the beginning, and deleting the last row, of the column of interest. See [this](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/07/12/fast-and-easy-way-to-reference-previous-or-next-rows-in-power-query-or-power-bi/) for a discussion.

Comment: Just noticed that, although your question title references Power Query, your question indicates you want to do this in Power Pivot.  I can help with the former, but not the latter. Which do you want?

Comment: Argh. That should read powerquery. I'll change it. I'm doing the work in powerBI but the etl/stuff behind the scenes is done using transform / powerquery.

Comment: Thanks Ron. That link gives a further link to a way to do it in DAX using LOOKUPVALUE. That's interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get you started in Power Query.

Here is a method of generating separate running totals for males and females.

It is written as a separate function, so could be used on Grouped tables also.

It uses the `List.Generate` function, as well as a `Buffered List` for speed.

**fnRunningTotal**

```
(values as list) as list =>
let 
    RT = List.Generate(
            ()=> [RT = values{0}, counter = 0],
            each [counter] < List.Count(values),
            each [RT = [RT] + values{[counter]+1}, counter = [counter]+1],
            each [RT]
    )
in 
    RT
```

**Main MCode** *edited to shorten the code a bit*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Location", type text}, {"Gender", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"TotalPop", Int64.Type}}),

//add custom columns to separate by Gender
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "maleValue", each if [Gender] = "M" then [Value] else 0),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "femaleValue", each if [Gender] = "F" then [Value] else 0),

//running totals for each Gender column
    buffMale = List.Buffer(#"Added Custom1"[maleValue]),
    buffFemale = List.Buffer(#"Added Custom1"[femaleValue]),
    RT = Table.FromColumns(
            List.Combine({Table.ToColumns(#"Added Custom1"),
                          {fnRunningTotal(buffMale), fnRunningTotal(buffFemale)}}),
            List.Combine({Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom1"),
                          {"runningTotalMale","runningTotalFemale"}})
        ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(RT,{"maleValue", "femaleValue"})    
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

**Original**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron. This is really helpful of you. As it uses buffered lists, is it hampered by table size at all?

Comment: @damo I think you have to try it with and without buffering the list and see which performs better with your data.  I believe (not sure) that if the buffered list exceeds available memory, it may page out to the disk drive, so there are a lot of variables involved.  There's no **need** to use a buffered list; I was just trying to prevent excessive/unneeded repeat accesses to the original data. You could use unbuffered lists.   By the way, I edited the **M Code** in my answer to shorten it up a bit.  Still with the same results. But with very large datasets, I would test it both ways.